# Adding annother Class into an Existing class

Tags: java

So im pretty much asked to Simulate a Universe with two Planets , each planet will then have a Rocket on its surface.

The thing is , i'm getting errors everywhere when I'm trying to add the Planets to the Universe 
I was wondering if I should continue with the same Class or create a specific Class for the "Planet", also when I try to position the Planets it says that the method is unknown for that class , though we did an example in the lecture and there was no error back then

Here is the code

```
import gdi.univrse* 

public class SomeUniverse {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Universe u = new Universe (args);
        Planet Planet1 = new Planet(41 , 700,u);
        Planet Planet2 = new Planet(51 , 610,u);
        u.simulate();
    }
}
```

So basically it says the Constructor (double,double,Universe) is undefined 
And when I try to do it step by step it also doesn't work

Comment: Where is ur 'Planet' ? Add the code for it

Comment: looks like the `Planet` doesn't have the constructor `(double, double, Universe)`

Comment: Have you actually defined the Planet and Universe classes? If so could you possibly post them here as well? Another issue is that `import gdi.univrse*`  isn't a valid import statement. You need a dot before the `*`: `import gdi.univrse.*`

Comment: There is stil some things unclear 

my Class is : someUniverse which is also the name of my project 

Do I have to create classes for both of the Universe and the Planets?
When I remove the planets and simulate the Universe it works and shows a backgound

So do i have to declare annother class of Planets using 
public class Planets(
public static void ... 

?

Comment: Yep, you'll need classes for everything you instantiate (i.e. call `new XYZ()` on).

Answer (score 1):

I deleted my previous answer as it turns out the classes `Planet` and `Universe` *do* exist, you just aren't using them correctly.

The `Planet` class defines it's constructor(s) like this:

```java
public Planet(double x, double y) {
    this();
    this.setLocation(x, y);
}

public Planet() {
    createdInstances.add(this);
    this.planet = new gdi.scene.universe.Planet();
}
```

Which means you must create a planet with either no arguments or with an x and y, like so:

```java
Planet myPlanet = new Planet(41, 700); // Location is set to 41, 700
Planet mySecondPlanet = new Planet(); // Location defaults to 0, 0
```

To add a planet to the universe you simply call `addEntity(myPlanet)` on the universe like so:

```java
import gdi.universe.* 

public class SomeUniverse {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Universe universe = new Universe(args);
        Planet firstPlanet = new Planet(41, 700);
        Planet secondPlanet = new Planet(51, 610);

        universe.addEntity(firstPlanet);
        universe.addEntity(secondPlanet);
        universe.simulate();
    }
}
```

It looks like the `gdi` package is a custom library written by whoever gave it to you (I assume your school / university), they should provide some documentation somewhere on it.

Comment: I think so , 
I think just didn't know "how to use the library " 
What i'm asked to do Is to use methods not to create ones I think I didn't quite understood it at First

All in all thank you for you Help :D !

Answer (score -1):

Your import statement is incorrerct. If you're trying to import all classes in that package, then you should write

```
import gdi.univrs.*    // assuming you meant to leave out the first 'e'
```

I recommend, instead, that you import classes individually. You say there is a planet class already, in that case I suggest that you import it for use explicitly:

```
import gdi.universe.Planet    // assuming it really has two 'e's
```

One reason for this is that, if that class does not exist, or is not available on your compile-time classpath, the compiler will tell you. Then you will know that is the problem, and solve it before you go looking for something else wrong.

Now, if the classes already exist, then their constructors are already defined. You need to either read some documentation that tells you what the legal constructors are, or get that information some other way (Eclipse, for instance, will give you a message saying what parameters are expected if you write the wrong ones). You can only use the constructors the class defines.